In what sense is the identification of $\Gamma(\operatorname{Spec} A, \mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec} A})$ with $A$ natural?
When working with schemes, one frequently replaces "an affine scheme $X$" with "an affine scheme $\operatorname{Spec} A$, where $A$ is a ring."
I would like to understand better the sense in which this identification is "natural." In Hartshorne, it is proven that there is an isomorphism between the $A$ and the global sections of $\operatorname{Spec} A$, but there is not discussion of the naturality of this isomorphism.
My category theory is not too strong, so I may be way off base here, but it seems like there should be a statement along the lines of: the inclusion of the category of spectra of commutative rings into the category of affine schemes is (left or right?) adjoint to the functor that takes an affine scheme $X$ to $\operatorname{Spec} \Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$?
Essentially, I am just looking for a rigorous statement of the properties of this isomorphism that tells me what I need to worry about checking when replacing an arbitrary affine scheme with spec of a ring.
I hope this question makes sense, as it is still somewhat vague in my head!

The situation can be summarised as follows.
There is a functor $\mathrm{Spec}:\mathrm{CRing}^{op} \to \mathrm{Sch}$ (from the the opposite of the category of commutative rings to schemes) and a functor $\Gamma: \mathrm{Sch} \to \mathrm{CRing}^{op}$ sending $X \mapsto \Gamma(X,\mathcal O_X)$.
$\mathrm{Spec}$ has essential image $\mathrm{Aff}$ (by definition), and one checks that, upon restricting to functors between $\mathrm{CRing}^{op}$ and $\mathrm{Aff}$, they constitute an equivalence of categories. Doing so requires some work of course.
Moreover, it is true that the $\Gamma$ and $\mathrm{Spec}$ functors participate in an adjunction. More precisely, there are natural bijections $$\mathrm{Hom}_{CRing}(A,\Gamma(X)) \simeq \mathrm{Hom}_{Sch}(X,\mathrm{Spec}\,A)$$ This can all be found in Hartshorne Chap II (mostly II.2)

Other than the intuitive meaning, formally natural means that it commutes with morphisms. Give a ring homomorphism $A\to B$, it induces a homomorphism between the global sections of $\text{Spec}(A)$ and $\text{Spec}(B)$, and these identifications induce a commutative diagram.
One important example is when $B=A_f$, a localization of $A$ by some element. In this case, the ring of global sections of $A_f$ is isomorphic to $O_{\text{Spec}(A)}(D(f))$, and the localization homomorphism $A\to A_f$ induces the homomorphism of global sections which is just the restriction map $O_{\text{Spec}(A)}(\text{Spec}(A))\to O_{\text{Spec}(A)}(D(f))$.

I guess I'm looking for a formalization of this statement though - it seems you are saying that these isomorphisms constitute a natural isomorphism between two functors, but what are the functors involved? This is why I was hoping there was a way of phrasing this where the isomorphisms are the unit/counit for some adjunction
